# Tinymce listbox onsubmit giving [object object] rather than value

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

I am trying to develop a wordpress plugin and all other thing went good. but i am stuck here at the moment. i am trying to get selected value from the tinymce listbox but it returns something like [object Object] rather than value. can any one tell me why this happening and give me a solution. i am very thankful if anyone can give me a solution for this issue.

```
(function() {
        tinymce.PluginManager.add('AP_tc_button', function( editor, url ) {
            editor.addButton( 'AP_tc_button', {
                text: 'My test button',
                icon: 'wp_code',
                onclick: function() {
        editor.windowManager.open({
            title: 'Select Your AD',
            body: [
            {
                type: 'listbox', 
                name: 'level', 
                label: 'Header level', 
               values: [{text: 'x', value: 'x'}]
            }],
            onsubmit: function(v) {
                alert(v);
                //editor.insertContent(toString(e.value()));
            }
        });
    }
            });
        });


    })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i found the solution i will add it here for your reference.

we have to get data from the object so i used object.data.listbox_name

```
onsubmit: function(v) {
            alert(v.data.level)
```